# How to merge unversioned code into Git repository?

Tags: git, merge, repository, diff, azure-devops

So a friend worked on a bunch of code that he never versioned, and is handing it off to me. He initially gave me version A, even though he had a more recent version B available. I put A into a git repository (on say Visual Studio Team Services), and then made some commits, resulting in version C. Now he has put up version B in a git repository (on say Bitbucket). How can I compare versions C and B, and merge all diffs between (B,A) and (C,A) to get one final version D which has both his updates and mine? Keep in mind, the repos on Bitbucket and TFS (versions B and C respectively) have no common git commits, although they both come off the same base version A.

I can see a couple of ways of doing this, not sure of the cons of each though:
1) Add Bitbucket version B as an upstream to my TFS version C, and fetch upstream/master, then do a git diff.
2) Copy the files from version B into the directory that holds version C, and then commit them as if I changed the files manually.
3) Something else entirely, like rebase.

My understanding of git is very basic so please explain like I'm 5 (well, not really, but you know what I mean).

Note: It is ok to have all changes made from A to B in one commit in the final repo history, but would be nice to preserve the individual commits between A and C.

Also, from version A to version B, the friend has not maintained directory structure, he has moved all the contents to a sub-directory of the root. So if version A had file a.txt, version B has file TRUNK/a.txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

- checkout `A`
- make a new branch from `A`
  [image] (from "[Git version control and Team Foundation Build](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/26/visual-studio-2013-preview-version-control-tfbuild.aspx#fragment-151986)")
- copy `B` in it
- add and commit:
  [image] (from "[Create, Connect, and Publish using Visual Studio with Git](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/06/set-up-connect-and-publish-using-visual-studio-with-git.aspx)")
- merge that branch in your main branch which represents `C`
  [image]
- resolve conflicts:
  [image: http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-45-92-2013-06-visual_2D00_studio_2D00_2013_2D00_preview_2D00_version_2D00_control_2D00_tfbuild/7506.VCtrlConflictsMergeWindow.png]